# SharePoint Column Name "Name" The column name that you entered is already in use or reserved. Choose another name

Tags: column

I am trying to change a column named `Name1` to `Name` but it's returning an error message

> The column name that you entered is already in use or reserved. Choose another name

I tried but it doesn't seem like it's a hidden column name.

```
javascript:g_FieldName={};alert('Successfully cleared reserved columns');
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name is the reserved field for file names in Document Libraries. You'll need to give Name1 a more contextual value, like Item Name, or Department Name.